# AEM Package of type 'MIXED' is legacy

Tags: aem, upgrade, jackrabbit, aem-6

I work in a project (Upgrade from AdobeExperienceManager 6.1 to 6.3 to 6.5) where after the Jackrabbit filevault-package-maven-plugin upgrade to version `1.3.2` the following error occurs:

```
Package of type 'MIXED' is legacy. Use one of the other types instead! @ META-INF/vault/properties.xml, validator: jackrabbit-packagetype
```

I searched the code, there is no single occurrence of the word "MIXED". The field `properties.xml` exists but does not contain any of the information mentioned in the error.
My search is stuck on this `properties.xml`. The information that it is legacy didn't help much since there is no documented migration path I could find on experienceleague or adobe help.

Any suggestions what to change or what exactly does this error means?

Answer (score 1):

As of the `[jackrabbit.apache.org][1]` -documentation the error refers to the `package type`.
Mixed packages are a model of the past (AEM 6.3).

Means to fix it we have to separate `Application` `/apps` `/libs` means all the `OSGi` stuff and all the rest as `Content`.

```
project
 - app
  - src/main/content/jcr_root
   - apps
   - content
   - etc
   - libs
  - META-INF
```

has to be split in Application-(code) my-project-package-bundle:

```
project
 - app
  - src/main/**java/com/project**/packageName
  - src/main/**test/com/project**/packageName
```

and Content (config, templating, other data that is no java/kotlin) my-project-package-content:

```
project
 - app
  - src/main/**resources**/jcr_root
   - content
   - component-dialogs
   - pages-config
   - etc
  - META-INF
```